# $scope.$on('element') watchers are not being triggered after $scope.element is set

Tags: angularjs

This is a controller where I am getting some data from firebase and updating my scope, then I want to do some more stuff once that scope is updated:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseAuth','$firebaseObject','$location',
'localStorageService','$q',
function($scope,$firebaseAuth,$firebaseObject,$location,
    localStorageService,$q) {

// Called
$scope.googleAuth = function(){
    var auth = $firebaseAuth();

    auth.$signInWithPopup("google").then(function(firebaseUser){
        // Google approved

        // Step 1. Get user profile
        getProfile(firebaseUser);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Authentication failed:",error);
        $scope.errorMsg = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
    });
}

// Watchers
$scope.$on('profile',function(){
    console.info("REACH");
    if($scope.profile == null){ // User doesn't exist
        console.info("profile null");
        if(isAssigned(firebaseUser) != null){
            // Redirect to create a profile page
        } else {
            // Do not let them in TODO: adjust the text
            $scope.erorrMsg = "It seems you don't have a profile. Please contact us on ----------- to get a profile";
        }
    } else {
        // Step 2. Get user parent info
        // getParent($scope.profile.current_centre_id,$scope.profile.refer_id);
        console.info("Getting parent");
        getParent('-KeVj_sr-uCY3zx0kbb6','-KeVpUA4OIK4msNIl0gQ');
    }
});

// After getting parent info
$scope.$on('parent',function(){
    localStorageService.set('currentUser',{
        profile: $scope.profile,
        parent: $scope.parent
    });
});

var getProfile = function(firebaseUser){
    var email = firebaseUser.user.email;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    // Getting profile
    $scope.profile = $firebaseObject(ref.child('profiles').orderByChild('email').equalTo('dev.beezbutt@gmail.com'));
}

var getParent = function(centre_id,parent_id){
    $scope.parent = $firebaseObject(ref.child('parents/'+centre_id+'/'+parent_id));
}

var isAssigned = function(firebaseUser){
    // TODO
    return false;
}
```

}]);

`$scope.$on('profile')` & `$scope.$on('parent')` are not being triggered, and I'm not sure why or what am I missing.

I know that `$scope.profile` is being set because I'm printing it in html.

Comment: For watching the scope variables, use $watch instead of $on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$scope.$on`, use `$scope.$watch` to watch the scope variables.

```
$scope.$watch("scope_variable_name", function(newVal, oldVal){
   // Add your code here
});
```